# 'Ok Google' doesn't work on LG G3

Tags: google, voice-recognition, lg-g3, ok-google

Recently the "Ok Google" feature no longer works on my LG G3, unless I factory reset my settings. But after a few hours it stops working again even if I don't change any of my settings back. I even upgraded my phone to Lollipop, but that didn't help either. Also, I tried reprogramming my voice back into my phone via "Google settings", but it won't pick up my voice either. 
So long story short the only way I can get it to pick up my voice is by clicking the microphone.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure "ok  Google" detection is on for every screen. Do this by opening the Google app, navigate to settings > voice > "ok Google detection" and make sure the "from any sceen" option is enabled. Hopefully this solves your problem.

Comment: I can't enable it anymore. When I try to set up the recognition to enable that feature, it won't pick up my voice

Comment: Are you sure your microphone is working?

Comment: Yes, the microphone works because I make calls a lot, and Google will pickup my voice if I click the Google Now microphone or the Talk to text microphone, just not for anything else.